# How to load data using custom PagingSourceand RemoteMediator in Paging3?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-paging, android-paging-3

I want to use custom PagingSource and RemoteMediator to load data ,because my Recyclerview have different kinds of data.

This is my PagingSource:

```
class MyPagingSource(
    db: AccountDatabase
) : PagingSource<Int, Any>() {

    val dao = db.dao()

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Any> {
        val list = ArrayList<Any>()

        try {
            val page = params.key ?: 1

            if (page == 1) {
                list.let {
                    val monthInOut = dao.getMonthInOut()
                    val dayInOut = dao.getDayInOut()
                    it.add(monthInOut)
                    it.add(dayInOut)
                }
            }

            val tmp = dao.getAll(params.loadSize, (page - 1) * params.loadSize)
            list.addAll(tmp)

            return LoadResult.Page(
                data = list,
                prevKey = null,
                nextKey = if (list.isEmpty()) null else page + 1
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            return LoadResult.Error(Throwable("network error"))
        }
    }


    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Any>) = null

}
```

This is my RemoteMediator:

```
class MyMediator(
    val service: Service,
    val db: AccountDatabase,
) : RemoteMediator<Int, Any>(

) {
    val constantDao: ConstantDao = BaseDatabase.instance.constantDao()
    val KEY = "KEY"
    private val dao: Dao = db.dao()

    private lateinit var page: String

    override suspend fun load(
        loadType: LoadType,
        state: PagingState<Int, Any>
    ): MediatorResult {
        try {
            page = when (loadType) {
                LoadType.REFRESH -> {
                    "1"
                }
                LoadType.PREPEND -> {
                    return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
                }
                LoadType.APPEND -> {
                    val constantKey = db.withTransaction {
                        constantDao.get(KEY)
                    }
                    constantKey.value
                }
            }

            if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
                val monthInCome =
                    service.getCurMonthInCome(1, state.config.pageSize).data.content[0]
                val monthOutCome =
                    service.getCurMonthOutCome(1, state.config.pageSize).data.content[0]
                val monthInOut = MonthInOut(monthOutCome, monthInCome)

                val dayInCome = service.getCurDayInCome(1, state.config.pageSize).data.content[0]
                val dayOutCome = service.getCurDayOutCome(1, state.config.pageSize).data.content[0]
                val dayInOut = DayInOut(dayOutCome, dayInCome)

                db.withTransaction {
                    dao.clearDay()
                    dao.clearMonth()
                    constantDao.delete(KEY)
                    dao.insert(monthInOut)
                    dao.insert(dayInOut)

                }

            }
            val list =
                service.get(
                    pageNum = page.toInt(),
                    pageSize = if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) state.config.initialLoadSize else state.config.pageSize
                ).data.content

            page =
                (page.toInt() + if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) state.config.initialLoadSize / state.config.pageSize else 1).toString()


            db.withTransaction {
                if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
                    dao.clearItem()
                }
                dao.insert(list)
                constantDao.insert(ConstantKey(KEY, page))
            }
            return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = list.isEmpty())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            return MediatorResult.Error(Throwable(message = "网络错误"))
        }
    }


}
```

This is Dao:

```
@Dao
interface Dao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(list: List<Account>)

    @Query("DELETE FROM account_cache ")
    suspend fun clearItem()

    @Query("DELETE FROM  account_month_cache")
    suspend fun clearMonth()

    @Query("DELETE FROM account_day_cache")
    suspend fun clearDay()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM account_cache  ORDER BY  (year*10000+month*100+day) LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset  ")
    suspend fun getAll(limit:Int,offset:Int): List<Account>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(monthInOut: MonthInOut)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(dayInOut: DayInOut)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM account_month_cache")
    suspend fun getMonthInOut(): MonthInOut

    @Query("SELECT * FROM account_day_cache")
    suspend fun getDayInOut(): DayInOut

}
```

In Fragment:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(exceptionHandler) {
    viewModel.captureList().collectLatest {
        adapter.submitData(it)
    }
}
```

In ViewModel:

```
fun captureList() = 
    Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(pageSize = 5),
        remoteMediator = MyMediator(service, db)
    ) {
        MyPagingSource(db)
    }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

Because  I have different kinds of the data , so I try to use `Any`,then I cast it in `Adapter`.

Now the problem is: When I first load the data, because there is nothing in `Room`,so the page is empty....... Althouth the `MyMediator` will load the data from `network`, but because the `MyMediator` is execute after `MyPagingSouce`, So the recyclerview is still empty.

### I want to know how to inform `MyPagingSource` that the new data is already load by `MyMediator`, so that `MyPagingSource` can load the new data from `Room`.

Comment: @dlam, could you help me ? thanks.

Answer (score 4):

implement below code in your custom PagingSource:

```
init {
    db.invalidationTracker.addObserver(object : InvalidationTracker.Observer(arrayOf(TABLE_NAME)) {
        override fun onInvalidated(tables: MutableSet<String>) {
            this@xxxPagingSource.invalidate()
        }
    })
}
```