# Get Room observable list with paging 3

Tags: android, android-room, android-paging-3

I'm using Paging 3 with a local database using Room, the @Query from Room is the following:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Channel LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset")
suspend fun getAllChannels(limit: Int, offset: Int): List<Channel>
```

Then i get my data in the PagingSource like this, and return the LoadResult.Page with my data

```
channels = channelDao.getAllChannels(
    params.loadSize,
    position * params.loadSize
)

return LoadResult.Page(
    data = channels,
    prevKey = if (position == INITIAL_INDEX) null else position - 1,
    nextKey = if (mData.isEmpty()) null else position + 1
)
```

in my repository, i get the channels like this:

```
override fun getAllChannels(): Flow<PagingData<Channel>> {
return Pager(
    PagingConfig(
        pageSize = 20,
        enablePlaceholders = false,
        initialLoadSize = 20
    )
) {
    ChannelPagingSource(
        channelDao
    )
}.flow
}
```

The problem with this approach is that my view can't observe any modifications happening on the Channel objects, so if it gets updated there's no way to be notified. Is it possible to get observable objects using pagination?

An alternative way is to drop the paging and just return a Flow<List> from Room and consume it, but it's heavy and slowing down the app a little.

Comment: If you want to invalidate your existing custom PageSource to update the UI based on changes occurring in the database, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/71168286/5376678

Answer (score 4):

1. Add the `room-paging` [dependency](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room) in your gradle module. With that Room can handle `PagingSource` objects in queries.

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:2.5.0"
```

2. Create a method that returns `PagingSource<Int, EntityDb>` in your `@Dao interface`. `Int` - [page number / offset](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingSource#PagingSource()), `EntityDb` - your database model, in your case `Channel`.

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM Channel")
fun pagingSource(): PagingSource<Int, Channel>
```

3. Get flow of `PagingData` from your repository.

```kotlin
fun observePagingSource(): Flow<PagingData<Channel>> {
  return Pager(
       config = PagingConfig(pageSize = 20, initialLoadSize = 20),
       pagingSourceFactory = { channelDao.pagingSource() }
  ).flow
}
```

---

### One important thing - use a single instance of your Dao

If you insert/update/delete data in one instance of your Dao and observe it changes in the other one - **you won't receive updates**.